# How do I merge multiple FLV files using FLV::Splice module?

Tags: perl, flv

If I have an array that contains multiple FLV files like so:

```
my @src_files = qw (1.flv 2.flv 3.flv 4.flv 5.flv 6.flv 7.flv);
```

I can call [flvbind](http://www.flvsoft.com/bind_flv/).exe as an external commandline program to do the merging like so:

```
my $args = join(' ',@src_files);
my $dest_file = 'merged.flv';
system "flvbind $dest_file $args";
```

But the usage example for [FLV::Splice](http://search.cpan.org/~cdolan/FLV-Info-0.24/lib/FLV/Splice.pm) is this:

```
use FLV::Splic; 
my $converter = FLV::Splice->new();
$converter->add_input('first.flv');
$converter->add_input('second.flv');
$converter->save('output.flv');
```

I seem to be unable to figure out how to do the same thing like the flvbind does.
Do I have to verbosely add every param like so:

```
use FLV::Splice;

my $dest_file = 'merged.flv';
my $converter = FLV::Splice->new();
$converter->add_input('1.flv');
$converter->add_input('2.flv');
$converter->add_input('3.flv');
$converter->add_input('4.flv');
$converter->add_input('5.flv');
$converter->add_input('6.flv');
$converter->add_input('7.flv');
$converter->save("$dest_file");
```

This does not look like the correct way. I mean do I have to verbosely add every param? Is there a way to simplify the repeated use of the add_input method? Any pointers? Thanks like always :)

UPDATE:
   It turns out that this is a silly question. Thanks, @Eric for giving me the correct answer. I thought of using a for loop to reduce the repeated use of the add_input method but somehow I thought it would not work and I thought I was stuck. Well, I'll be reminding myself not to easily bother other people next time.

Comment: i dont know what is the proccess that flvbind.exe does but FLV::Splice only tries to merge the files and nothing else which i wouldnt be surprise if it does not work... more over at the module page there is also this: `This tool may also produce unplayable content if the segments have different framerates. That depends on the player implementation.` If flvbind has a encoding process then you should just stick to it instead.

Comment: @Prix, thanks for the comment. Yes, FLV::Splice sometimes does not work. But I was asking if there is a way to simplify the repeated use of the add_input method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly easy to reduce the repetition:

```
$converter->add_input($_) for @src_files;
```

Or wrap the whole thing in a subroutine:

```
sub flv_splice {
    my $dest_file = shift;
    my $converter = FLV::Splice->new();
    $converter->add_input($_) for @_;
    $converter->save($dest_file);
}

flv_splice 'merged.flv', @src_files;
```

Comment: thanks. Does this work? I thought of using for loops too. Well, I'll be giving it a test.

Comment: I can't say anything about `FLV::Splice` the module, I haven't used it (but will be giving it a try at some point, seems interesting), this is how to reduce the repetition and make it easier to use.

Comment: haha, yes, it does work! I thought of using a for loop and then somehow I thought it wouldn't work and then I thought I was stuck.